# "Какой из..." или "Кто из..."?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Подскажите, какая форма вопроса правильная:

1) Какой из писателей XIX века сделал что-то?

2) Кто из писателей XIX века сделал что-то?

Являются ли они равноправными или какой-то вариант является речевой ошибкой?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

Вариант "**Кто**?" универсален: он может задаваться практически в любой ситуации и допускает множественный выбор в ответе.

Вариант "**Какой из...**?" подразумевает, что задающий этот вопрос знает ответ, и этот ответ указывает только на *одного* писателя. Такой вопрос подходит для загадки или для викторины с предлагаемыми вариантами ответа, один из которых правильный.

Comment: _Вариант "Который?" подразумевает..._ В вопросе — **какой из...** Мне кажется, что разница есть.

Comment: Да, я не заметил (по рассеянности), изменю. Спасибо.

Comment: Alex_ander, спасибо. Я не уточнил в вопросе (т.к. не подумал, что это важно), что речь как раз о викторине с несколькими вариантами ответов и одним правильным. Получается, как раз этот вариант у Вас и рассмотрен.

Answer (score 2):

Возможно, я буду не совсем прав, но я бы употребил ***кто из***, когда речь про всех писателей вообще или про писателей какой-то страны *(кто из русских писателей).* А ***какой из***, по-моему, подходит для случая, когда *перечислено* какое-то количество писателей и стоит вопрос, *какой из **этих** писателей что-то сделал.*

Поэтому из Ваших примеров в случае с XIX веком я бы выбрал второй вариант — ***кто*** (ведь за весь XIX век было очень много писателей).